# Which condition is true in While?

Tags: c, c99

Sorry if this is too simple. I want to know which of the conditionals is happening exactly. Is there a way more able to capture this without repeating them inside the block with if structures? I am using C language.

```
while ( l < 0 || l > 2 || c < 0 || c > 2 )
```

Comment: Alternatively, if this is for debugging then you can just print out the values of `l` and `c`.

Comment: Thanks, but actually I want to get the program to do different things for each condition, indeed, they all would pass threw a scanf in all iterations, but each one has a different printf to show a type of "error", to be more specific. The user can`t enter a number that does not satisfy these conditions, and will be told to enter new numbers until all conditions can be satisfied.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use comma expressions, i.e. something like `(expr1,expr2)`, which are always evaluated left to right with a sequence point at each `,`; So you may rely on that `expr1` is evaluated before `expr2`, whereas the latter serves as the comma expression's result then.

With that, the following should work, and `x` will bee in the range of `0..3`, depending on which condition got true:

```
int x;
while ( (x=0,l < 0) || (++x,l > 2) || (++x,c < 0) || (++x,c > 2) )
```

Comment: You could reset in the condition: `while ((x = 0), (l < 0 || ...`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: "I want to know which of the conditionals is happening exactly": since the expression short-circuits, as soon as a condition is false, short circuit happens. This can be easily fixed by replacing `||` by `|` that said.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre That's precisely why this works. Short-circuiting means that the value of x is set depending on which condition was true.  If you "fix" it to not short-circuit, then x is always 3, and that's not very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign them "on the fly" to previously declared variables:

```
bool ll0, lg2, cl0, cg2;
while((ll0 = l<0) || (lg2 = l>2) || (cl0 = c<0) || (cg2 = c>2)) {
    if(ll0) {
        // l is less than 0
    } else if(lg2) {
        // l is greater than 2
    } else if(cl0) {
        // c is less than 0
    } else if(cg2) {
        // c is greater than 2
    }
    // ...
}
```

Notice the if-else chain, as, since the `||` operator short-circuits (i.e. the second operand isn't even evaluated if the first is already `true`), if e.g. `ll0` is true the other values aren't going to be correctly assigned.

That being said, to be honest I wouldn't bother - just repeat the conditional, if these are just integer variables these comparisons aren't going to cost you anything (actually, the compiler may even keep around the comparison value in some cases and recycle it).

Comment: NB: The flags after the first true flag can't be trusted, since `||` short-circuits.  That is, if `ll0` is false and `lg2` is true, the flags `cl0` and `cg2` were not changed this iteration.  (Due to that, you need to initialize at least the last three flags or the compiler is going to complain about using uninitialized variables.)

Comment: "the compiler may even keep around the comparison value in some cases and recycle it" Thanks for sharing that!

Comment: @cdhowie: Indeed, I'll add a warning about that!

Comment: @ArturRodriguesAguiar you are welcome, however keep in mind that these comparisons are extremely cheap, you shouldn't be worried about them unless you actually find them to be your bottleneck through profiling.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a loop without conditions, compute conditions in loop, and break if any of the conditions is true.

```
while (1)   // or for(;;)
{
  bool one = l < 0;
  bool two = l > 2;
  bool three = c < 0;
  bool four = c > 2;
  if (one || two || three || four) break;
  // bool variables are available there
}
```

If you want to get access to all conditions, you cannot use short-circuiting evaluation for them. So make sure you really want to store them beforehand.

Comment: This is probably the simplest answer given that doesn't have caveats.

Comment: @StephanLechner Except that does not change the observable behavior of the program.

Comment: @cdhowie: yes, of course. it might be that someone relies on "short-circuiting", but it may also be the case that one definitely does not want this short circuits. A common situation where one relies on it are `null`-checks of pointers used in the subsequent conditions. But of course, as said, it's not meant as a critique but just as a note that there actually may be some difference in behaviour.